# How to find Distinc from the multiple lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, list, linq, distinct

I need to find all the distinct items (religions) from the entire collection of countries, where everyone of them has its own list of the items (religions). Here is my object class:

```
public class Country
    {        
        public string Name { get; }
        public List<string> Religions { get; }

        public Country(string name, List<string> religions)
        {
             Name = name;
             Religions = religions;
        }

        public static List<Country> GetCountries()
        {
             return new List<Country>()
             {
                  new Country( "Venezuela", new List<string> { "Roman Catholic", "Protestant" } ),
                  new Country( "Peru", new List<string> { "Roman Catholic", "Evangelical" } ),
                  new Country( "Paraguay", new List<string> { "Roman Catholic", "Protestant" } ),
                  new Country( "Bolivia", new List<string> { "Roman Catholic", "Evangelical", "Protestant" } )
             };  
        }
       
        public override string ToString() =>
                  $"\n{Name} \nReligions: {string.Join(", ", Religions)}";
     }
```

Here is my Main class:

```
List<Country> countries = Country.GetCountries();

AllReligions(countries);

Console.ReadKey();

static void AllReligions(List<Country> countries) 
{
     var distinctReligions = countries
         .Select(r => new { r.Religions })
         .Distinct()
         .ToList();

     Console.WriteLine("Religions in South America:");
         foreach (var rel in distinctReligions)                
             Console.WriteLine(rel);
}
```

I am on my 5th iteration of the code and one of the problems is that I don't know where the error is happening - inside my DISTINCT function or inside my printout function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the printout:

[image: the output]

Comment: Both. The `Distinct()` operation only works in the anonymous objects, not their contents. All those objects are unique, so `Distinct()` doesn't do anything. `Console.WriteLine` works on the anonymous object, not the contents of the `Religions` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are wrong. Both work on the anonymous objects, not the religion strings.

To get the distinct religions you need to use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to "flatten" the country/religion graph:

```
IEnumerable<string> religions=Country
                             .GetCountries()
                             .SelectMany(country=>country.Religions)
                             .Distinct();

Console.WriteLine("Religions in South America:");

foreach (var rel in religions)   
{             
    Console.WriteLine(rel);
}
```

The equivalent in query form would be :

```
var religions = ( from country in Country.GetCountries()
                  from religion in country.Religions
                  select religion
                ).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here.

1. What you think you get with `.Select(r => new { r.Religions })` - it gives you list of lists. What you want is `SelectMany(r => r.Religions)` - that way, you will get list of religions, no list of anonymous objects with list in its property.
2. `Distinct` uses basic comparison, you need to write custom comparer and provide it to overload:

```
Distinct<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)
```

You need to implement `IEqualityComparer<Religion>`.

UPDATE: religion is just a string, so you do not need to implement one, after using `SelectMany` everything should be just fine.

3. Your "printout" function - you use `Console.WriteLine` which invokes just `ToString` on objects - as you have lists there, it looks weird :) After suggestion of using `SelectMany` it should go away.